# why does this function not work? I want it to count backwards from 10 to 1

Tags: javascript

I want it to count backwards from 10 to 1.

```js
function countdown(n) {
  if (n < 1) {
    return []
  } else {
    return countdown(n - 1).unshift(n);
  }
}
```

Comment: Return value of `unshift` is not an array.

Comment: unshift() is Array method! I don't see Array here

Comment: Start by looking at the error thrown in your debugging console

Comment: Suggest Correction in code to get an array with countdown as final output. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value returned by the function isn't an array. unshift has to be used only on array objects. There's many much simpler way to achieve what you are trying to do here.

I have mentioned a simple recursive function which achieves the same -

```js
function countdown(n) {
  console.log(n)
  // recursive till n becomes zero. When n === 0, just return 0
  return n ? countdown(n - 1) : 0;
}

countdown(10)
```

---

**NOTE :** The method you are using - [`unshift()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) returns new length property of the object upon which the method was called. So, if you want to have a countback array to be returned from the function, you could choose to use the following approach which uses recursion and `unshift()`, just as in your code with slight changes in code -

```js
function countdown(n) {
  if (n < 1) {
    return []
  } else {
    let z = countdown(n - 1);
    z.unshift(n);
    // return the array itslef so unshift() would work. Directly returning z.unshift would result in returning a number and not an array.
    return z;
  }
}
// will return countdown array
console.log(countdown(10))
```

There will probably be a better way to do this without using `unshift()` or recursion...but I have just shown an approach which can be used to achieve the desired result.

Comment: thank you. finally got it......unshift was  returning length of array.while i was expecting the array to be returned.

Answer (score 1):

unshift works on arrays. n is a number.

```js
function countdown(n){
  if (n < 1) {
    console.log(n)
    return n
  } else {
    console.log(n)
    return countdown(n-1);
  }
}

countdown(10)
```

Comment: they don't call unshift on `n`, though.